# Contact form using PHP mailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to add contact form using PHP mailer. when someone fill the form i should get in my mail and as well as the visitor who filed the form should get mail that his submission is successful.

Currently using

PHP code :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler();

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);




$pp->sendEmailTo('someone@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

HTML Code :

```js
$(function() {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

      jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function() {
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
        }
      });

    } //else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function() {
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json'
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>

  <form method="post" id="reused_form">
    <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="50">

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" required maxlength="50">

    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="Message" rows="10" maxlength="6000" required></textarea>
    <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
  </form>
  <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
    <h3>Submitted the form successfully!</h3>
    <p>
      We will get back to you soon.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
    <h3>Error</h3>
    Sorry there was an error sending your form.

  </div>
</div>
```

This code notify me about the submission but do not notify the visitor in there mail that there submission is successful.

The visitor should get mail from admin@example.com that your submission is successfully in there mail.

Comment: `sendEmailTo()` is sending an email to your address but not to the users address?

Comment: @ElvisPimentel yes right. how to add another function to confirmation email to visitor while form is submitted successfully.

Comment: I don't know what `sendEmailTo()` is, I added an answer based on PHP docs and an implementation I have currently working in my own site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a windows server for your php site:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
$mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also you would need to set headers like this:

```
// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

For Linux servers, you need to build a relay with and agent like postfix.

Here is the documentation for [mail function in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: I am using oracle ubuntu linux server with plesk control panel. does your code work in linux?

Comment: You can use fsocket: https://schoudhury.com/blog/articles/send-email-using-gmail-from-php-with-fsockopen/

Comment: Do a research on this repository: https://github.com/yidas/php-socket-mailer is socket based too.

Comment: Thanks for reference but too confuse on integrating with my code